# How to get same server response data for two different application?

Tags: android-lvl

I'am using LVL to get server response data. I want to know if I can get the same server response data for my two different applications and if so, what changes I have to do in LVL to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This can only happen if you are using the same SALT for both your applications. I am also modifying LicenseCheckerCallback to return userid, packagename and versioncode to the application. I then store it for local usage. The good part is that I can now do activation checks once. But I have to do it again when the version number is upgraded. And ofcourse I check the local storage first for a valid activation before asking LVL to check.